# Invalid Argument error when calling signJWT

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, jwt

I am following this documentation https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/credentials/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/signJwt to generate a signed JWT

Path Parameter:
`name: projects/-/serviceAccounts/test-acc@123.iam.gserviceaccount.com`

This is my request body

```
{
  "delegates": []
  "payload": "{'sub': 'test-acc@123.iam.gserviceaccount.com', 'iat': 1661250118, 'exp': 1661253718, 'aud': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/iam'}"
}
```

I am getting this invalid argument error.

Am I missing something in the payload?
[image]

I dont think I have any issues with permission as I was able to get success response when I tried generateAccessToken api call

Comment: You're missing a comma after `"delegates": [],` in the request body.

Comment: This worked for me by replacing all single quotes ( ' ) with \" (escaping double quotes) '{\"aud\":\"value\"}'

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a comma after `"delegates": [],` in the request body. It should follow the structure:

```
{
  "delegates": [
    string
  ],
  "payload": string
}
```

Comment: This worked for me by replacing all single quotes ( ' ) with \" (escaping double quotes)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me by replacing all single quotes ( ' ) with \" (escaping double quotes)

{
"delegates": [],
"payload": "{"sub": "test-acc@123.iam.gserviceaccount.com", "iat": 1661250118, "exp": 1661253718, "aud": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/iam"}"
}